# Data format for Cartesian mesh with cut cells

Tags: mesh, data-structures

Is there a mesh data format which is particularly well suited for Cartesian meshes with Dey-Mittra style cut-cells? Ideally, one which does not require converting the cut-cells into a more general polyhedron.

Non-proprietary formats with open-source implementations are also preferable.